# python ConfigParser module

Tags: python, configparser

I have the following ini file

```
[Section]
value=test
```

When i use the ConfigParser Module :

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
str=config.get('Section', 'value')

if str == 'test':
    print 1

else :
    print 0
```

it always print 0 could someone help

Comment: The sample works perfectly for me (and prints 1)

Comment: `str` is a very bad name for the variable in python (redefines built-in type `str`)

Comment: `str` is the name of a built-in `type`. While you can re-use it like this, it generally best not to.

Comment: @van No it does not redefine the built-in type `str`, it just removes a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
print str
```

and see what the value is.